# USING THE SENSOR INVARIANT ATMOSPHERIC CORRECTION - SIAC, CREATING AN IMAGE COLLECTION WITH THE OUTPUT FOR FURTHER ANALYSIS IN GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction, median, imagecollection

My aim is to atmospherically correct sentinel 2 level 1c image in Ethiopia, and then perform a cloud mask.
My next aim is to create a monthly median composite of the atmospherically corrected / Cloud masked image to obtain a monthly composite for January 2017

I have two problems.

First, I performed an Atmospheric correction in GEE using the SIAC method on Sentinel 2 Level 1c for Ethiopia, and the output is an image collection that does not have the QA bands, so I cannot proceed with the cloud masking.

Secondly, I try to create a median image of the output (which is already an image collection), and I keep getting an error, "Line 52: b.call is not a function"

I then try to convert the image collection (which is already in my code) to an asset and I get the error "ImageCollection (Error)
ImageCollection.load: ImageCollection asset 'siacCollection' not found (does not exist or caller does not have access)."

Here is my code below

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

// SIAC atmospheric correction module
var siac = require('users/marcyinfeng/utils:SIAC');

// Map the function over one month of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-01-31')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .filterBounds(Ethiopia)
                  //.median
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

Map.addLayer(dataset,{bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.4})

// / Function to perform atmospheric correction using Sen2Cor
  var siacCollection = dataset.map(function(image){
  var correctedImage = siac.get_sur(image).copyProperties(image,['system:time_start','system:time_end','QA60']);
  return correctedImage;
});

var ACimages = ee.ImageCollection('siacCollection')

//Visualization parameters
var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 3000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.setCenter(38.763611,9.005401, 6);
Map.addLayer(dataset, rgbVis, 'RGB');
Map.addLayer(siacCollection, {bands:"B4,B3,B2", min: 0.0, max: 0.2, gamma: 1.4}, 'Corrected Image');

print(ACimages)
```

How can I easily export the image collection to the specified image collection asset?

Comment: Please DO NOT USE ALLCAPS in your question titles.  It can be interpreted as SHOUTING.

Comment: Using ALL-CAPS gets attention, but unfortunately, the attention it gets are down-votes for cluttering the feed with difficult to read noise.

Answer (score 2):

> First, I performed an Atmoshperic correction in GEE using the SIAC method on Sentinel 2 Level 1c for Ethiopia, and the output is an image collection that does not have the QA bands, so I cannot proceed with the cloud masking.

If the SIAC method removes QA bands needed for cloud masking, you should perform cloud-masking before atmospheric correction. From your code example, it looks like you're already doing this. Note that you will also probably get better results if you apply atmospheric correction before generating the median collection instead of applying it *to* the median collection. That will be slower and require more memory, but generate a more accurate composite.

In other words, I would try using something like the code below to define your dataset:

```js
var siacCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-01-31')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .filterBounds(Ethiopia)
                  // Apply cloud-masking to each image
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  // Apply SIAC to each image
                  .map(siac.get_sur)
                  // Combine all masked, corrected images with a median
                  .median();
```

> Secondly, I try to create a median image of the output (which is already an image collection), and I keep getting an error, "Line 52: b.call is not a function"

The problem here is that you're using `collection.median` when you need to *call* the function instead, like `collection.median()`. Otherwise, you're just assigning the function to your dataset and GEE gets confused.

> I then try to convert the image collection (which is already in my code) to an asset and I get the error "ImageCollection (Error) ImageCollection.load: ImageCollection asset 'siacCollection' not found (does not exist or caller does not have access)."

If you want to access `siacCollection` as an asset, you'll need to use [`Export.image.toAsset`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-toasset) to save it first. This is only needed if the collection is too slow to process on-the-fly or you want to access it from other scripts. Otherwise, you can skip the step of loading it from a new `ee.ImageCollection` since it's already defined.

Comment: Thank you for the initial response. The collection.median() worked, now I have a follow up question.
If i want to export image collection to asset for sentinel 2, can i choose not to select a scale, since the image contains many bands at different scales. How can I export the image without distorting the original scales

Comment: The processed median image still has clouds in my study area, is there a way I can completely discard them

Comment: Exporting with multiple scales is a good question. That's not possible as far as I know as it will default to 1000 if you leave it blank. You may want to create a separate question for that here or ask on the [Developers Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers).

Comment: To improve the cloud masking, you could try masking with the [Cloud Probability](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY) dataset, or the new [CloudScore+](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/GOOGLE_CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS_V1_S2_HARMONIZED) dataset, although I think data is still being processed for the latter so it may not be fully available yet. The code examples on those pages should get you started.